# Changing the end point of a path in raphael

Tags: jquery, raphael

I am trying to change the end point of a path drawn on a raphael canvas but cannot get the syntax right. Here is the code. (The arguments of the function call arrow.attr are obviously wrong but I have tried numerous combinations to no avail):

```
window.onload = function() {  
 var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);  
 var circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 80);  
 var arrow = paper.path("M 100 100 l -56.5 56.5 z"); 
    arrow.attr({stroke: '#0a0', 'stroke-width': 3});

    arrow.attr({'x2':80, 'y2':0});
}  ;
```

The raphael reference is very limited and I would like to know if there is a better reference somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to modify a part of the path is to store the path details in an array, modify parts as required and reassign the path as string.

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500),
    pathArray = ['M', 100, 100, 'l', 100, 100, 0, 100, 'z'],
    shape = paper.path(pathArray.join(' '));
// Modify the last point (0, 100) to (100, 0)
pathArray.splice(-3, 2, 100, 0);
// Reassign the path as string
shape.attr({path: pathArray.join(' ')})
```

Hope this helps.